# Does shift cipher with non-uniform plain text probability have perfect secrecy?

Tags: classical-cipher, perfect-secrecy

I am having a hard time grasping the perfect secrecy concept. (I have already tried solving a couple of similar problems, so please don't think I am trying to get you guys to do my work, I really am stumped on this).

Consider a shift cipher with plaintext, key and cipher-text space is $[0..7]$ i.e.

$$
P = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}\\
K = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}\\
C = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}
$$

plain-text's even alphabets have twice the probability of odd alphabet i.e.

$$
\forall p \in P: 
\Pr_P(p) = \begin{cases} \frac{2}{12} & \textrm{ if p = 2(b) for some b $\in$ Z } \\
\frac{1}{12} & \textrm{ if p = 2(b) + 1 for some b $\in$ Z }
\end{cases}\\
\\
\forall k \in K: \Pr_K(k) = \frac{1}{8}
$$

From here I have calculated that $\Pr_C(c) = \frac{1}{8}$.

1. How do I calculate $\Pr(y|x)$
2. How do I use Baye's theorem to calculate $\Pr(x|y)$
3. How do I show whether $\Pr(x|y) = \Pr(x)$ or $\Pr(x|y) \neq \Pr(x)$ (thereby determining whether this cipher has perfect secrecy or not).

Comment: $P(y|x) = P(x \cap y)/P(x)$.

Comment: actually you are specifying the general formula for probability, in crypto it's $P(y|x) = \sum_{(k: x = d_{k}(y))}\Pr_{K}(k)$, and it comes out as $\frac{1}{8}$. the formula for Baye's Theorem is $\Pr(x|y) = \frac{\Pr_P(x).\Pr(y|x)}{\Pr_C(y)}$, this is where it gets tricky,  since $\Pr_P(x)$ has two different probabilities (for even and odd alphabets).

Comment: and someone downvoted me, I have no idea why someone might think the question is bad.

Comment: I am not sure, but my guess would be: Because it isn't a question about crypto. Your questions are basic probability theory. Also there is no difference to the probabilities in crypto. In the case of assuming independent $k$ and $x$(or independent $k$ and $c$) allows the multiplication of probabilities instead of summing up. That's pretty much the basic rule for conditional probabilities.

Comment: you do have a point (re: question being more about probability than crypto), i stand corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of perfect secrecy, no assumption about the distribution of plaintext is made - and it is not necessary.

Informally: If you are given any $p$ and a uniformly distributed $k$, then $p+k$ (with the according modulus) is also distributed uniformly , regardless of what $p$ actually was.

Your questions are a little surprising, because you seem to know about [Bayes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem). But on the other hand, it seems you are not familiar with the basic rules of [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability). For example, that for independent events $A$ and $B$ (in this case: $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$), the following holds:

$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B )}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A) \cdot P(B)}{P(B)} = P(A)$

Then, Bayes theorem is simply the combination of the very definitions of conditional probabilities, for both $P(A|B)$ and $P(B|A)$, regardless if they are independent or not:

$P(A|B) \cdot P(B) = P(A \cap B) = P(B|A) \cdot P(A)$

All your questions can be answered, if you just apply the rules and definitions for conditional probabilities.

Comment: you are right, may be I have been over-thinking the problem, I need to take a step back and think about it in terms of probability.

Answer (score 2):

For any ciphertext $c \in C$ and message $p \in P$ we have
$$P(c|p) = \frac{P(p\cap c)}{P(p)} = \frac{P(p\cap k)}{P(p)},$$
where $k = c-p$. This is because if the plaintext is $p$, the ciphertext is $c$ if and only if the key is $k$. Now, if the key is chosen independently of the plaintext we have $P(p\cap k) = P(p)\cdot P(k)$, and so finally $P(c|p) = P(k) = 1/8$ if the key is chosen uniformly.